# Spyne - GET with multiple paths instead of parameters for the query

Tags: python, http, curl, get, spyne

I'm trying to create a service to stream some files to clients from the server. However, instead of a URL like this:

```sh
$ curl http://localhost:8000/get_file?path=file_name
```

the client requests the file like this:

```sh
$ curl http://localhost:8000/get_file/file_name
```

Is this possible in `Spyne`?

Looking at [`file_soap_http`](https://github.com/arskom/spyne/blob/354723434db322e87a37b98a8a62b731954651e7/examples/file_soap_http.py), I wrote the server as such:

```py
# server.py
from spyne import (
    Service, rpc, Application,
    String,
    ByteArray,
)
from spyne.protocol.http import HttpRpc
from spyne.protocol.soap import Soap11
from spyne.server.wsgi import WsgiApplication
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

class FileService(Service):
    @rpc(String, _returns=ByteArray)
    def get_file(ctx, file_name):
        print(file_name)


application = Application(
    [FileService],
    'FileService',
    in_protocol=HttpRpc(),
    out_protocol=Soap11(),
)

wsgi_application = WsgiApplication(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8000, wsgi_application)
    server.serve_forever()
```

This works well with URLs like `/get_file?path=file_name`, but for URLs like `/get_file/file_name`, it gives `Requested resource not found` error:

```
<soap11env:Envelope xmlns:soap11env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap11env:Body>
    <soap11env:Fault>
      <faultcode>soap11env:Client.ResourceNotFound</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Requested resource '{FileService}file_name' not found</faultstring>
      <faultactor></faultactor>
    </soap11env:Fault>
  </soap11env:Body>
</soap11env:Envelope>
```

I cannot change the fact that the client requests like this. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just to make sure: You want the request to come in via http (no xml involved) but you want the response to be a SOAP XML document?

Comment: @BurakArslan Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doable with [HttpPattern](http://spyne.io/docs/2.10/reference/protocol/http.html#spyne.protocol.http.HttpPattern).

First have a look at this:

https://github.com/arskom/spyne/blob/35fa93f1ac34f868b9d86c639b6e7687c1842115/examples/multiple_protocols/server.py

Once you run the daemon, go to:

- http://127.0.0.1:9910/soap/get_utc_time
- http://127.0.0.1:9910/json/get_utc_time

Or:

- http://127.0.0.1:9910/dyn/get_utc_time.json
- http://127.0.0.1:9910/dyn/get_utc_time.soap
- http://127.0.0.1:9910/dyn/get_utc_time.svg

etc.

In similar vein, here's how your code should look:

```py
class FileService(Service):
    @rpc(String, _returns=ByteArray,
        _patterns=[HttpPattern('/get_file/<file_name>')])
    def get_file(ctx, file_name):
        print(file_name)
```